# Grails and Solr

Tags: grails, solr

I'm doing this project, in which i need to create a more powerfull GUI for apache solr `https://lucene.apache.org/solr`. I'm doing it with Grails, and basically, I just need to create a GUI which will manipulate solr url's and get me the results I need. The way im seing this, I can have my project Grails running at same time as Solr, nothing new here. But I would like to do it, but only have 1 server running. Is there any way to do this with Grails?

Comment: Hm, and what problem do you have? There is also solr-plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/solr if it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solr plugin embeds an instance of Solr - http://www.grails.org/plugin/solr - This might not be the best way for production, but it might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit late, but in case it helps someone else I'm adding my $.02.

Look at [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) for the java API to communicate from grails/groovy/java to a separate solr instance. It's quite easy, and once you get your head wrapped around using Solr's NamedLists for response info, you should have no trouble.

Mats Lindh has some further information on solrj: 
http://e-mats.org/2008/04/using-solrj-a-short-guide-to-getting-started-with-solrj/